# Change classes only for the child clicked within the parent using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I have two div's within a parent div. I need to change the classes for the child div which I clicked. For that I am writing a method to check which child was clicked and respectively I am trying to hide the other child div.
But I am not able to add classes or remove classes since the index is showing always as undefined. I am feeling there is some problem with the return statement.

```js
function changeClass() {

    const list = document.getElementById('my_div').children;
    const indx = this.getIndexOfParent(list);

      for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (indx === 0) {
          list[indx + 1].classList.add("d-none d-sm-block");
          list[indx].classList.remove("col-6 d-none d-sm-block");
        } else if (indx === 1) {
          list[indx - 1].classList.add("d-none d-sm-block");
          list[indx].classList.remove("col-6 d-none d-sm-block");
        }
        list[indx].classList.add("d-xs-block");
      }
      
  }

  function getIndexOfParent(child_list) {
    for (var i = 0, len = child_list.length; i < len; i++) {
      ((index) => {
        child_list[i].onclick = () => {
          return index;
        };
      })(i);
    }
}
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.row > div {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div  onclick="changeClass()" class="col-md-6 col-6">
     child-div-1
    </div>
    <div  onclick="changeClass()" class="col-md-6 col-6">
       child-div-2  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All I want is that, when I click on child-div-1 it should hide child-div-2 and vice versa **only for small screens** (which is why I am handling it by col-6 and d-xs-block classes)
Can anyone help me to solve the below problem.

Comment: This makes very little sense to begin with … you are adding a new additional click handler to all those elements every time changeClass is called.

Comment: If you are using that kind of old-school event handler binding via HTML attributes, `onclick="changeClass()"` – then you might as well pass an identifier or index to the function right there, `onclick="changeClass(0)"`, and use that to determine what you need to do.

Comment: Actually there is a button click from that I need to handle these, but for now I need to change these classes. Can you please show me the right way of doing it?

Comment: Child components are dynamically injected using angular, which is why I am unable to pass value inside the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `onclick` within the `for loop`. Instead add the class to the clicked `child div` and remove the class from it's sibling div.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.row > div')
  .forEach((div) => {
    div.addEventListener('click', function({
      target
    }) {
      target.classList.add('d-none', 'd-sm-block');
      const sibDiv = Array.prototype.filter.call(target.parentNode.children, div => div != target)[0];
      sibDiv.classList.remove('col-6', 'd-none', 'd-sm-block');
    });
  });
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.row>div {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
      child-div-1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
      child-div-2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

-- Edit --

The `return` statement will return the value of `index` to the `callback` function, you also need to add return to the callback function, so whatever result the callback function get will return to the function `getIndexOfParent`.

```js
function getIndex() {
    let i = 0;
    ((index) => {          // No return, logs undefined
        return index;
    })(i);
}
console.log(getIndex());
```

```js
function getIndex() {
    let i = 0;
    return ((index) => { // with return
        return index;
    })(i);
}
console.log(getIndex());
```

Comment: Good work:) I get it but why my return statement is not working when I put it inside the loop

Comment: @Onera - See edit, within the for loop you have call back function and the `return` statement return value to callback function. In order to return the callback function output to function `getIndexOfParent` prepend it with `return statement`. i:e `return ((index) => {`

Comment: Can you please explain this, Array.prototype.filter.call(target.parentNode.children, div => div != target)[0]; I am new to programming and finding it difficult to understand this.

Comment: `children` return `HTMLCollection`, which is not a regular array and filter work on regular array. So, `Array.prototype.filter` is used. The main purpose of `filter` used here is to get the sibling element. The first param in filter is `HTMLCollection` and second is callback function, which take each element from array as param, the `div => div != target` check if the div is not equal to the clicked `element`, if yes then it return the div else won't. `filter` return array, so to get the filtered element used `[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for your support pal:)

Answer (score 1):

I made a pen for solving this problem.
[Check the pen here](https://codepen.io/Ahmed_Gaafer/pen/qeZMab)

the solution is easy you simply have to write this line

`e.stopPropagation();`

this will stop the event from triggering on parent divs

basically what you are describing is called event bubbling.
you can read about it more on [medium](https://medium.com/@vsvaibhav2016/event-bubbling-and-event-capturing-in-javascript-6ff38bec30e)